# get value from a div or any container in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

While clicking the star in image given below I do following things,

```
<td>{{x.name}}</td>
<td>
    <div ng-click="starHovered($event)" class='pointer fg-blue'>{{x.star}} </div>
    <div title='Click to add star' class='displayNone'><input type="text-box" placeholder="Enter comments" class='commentsValue' ng-model='commentsValue'/><img  ng-click="starLeft($event,commentsValue)" class='pointer' src='images/add.png' height='30px'/></div>
</td>

$scope.starLeft = function(x,commentsValue,name){
    if(commentsValue =='' || commentsValue == undefined){
        alert('please enter comments');
        return;
    }

    alert(name)
}
```

How to get value in first cell, Name column of respective row or **

> to get text from any container in the DOM

**
I know jquery,can anyone suggest something similar to data attribute or jquery object
[table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXIh9.png)

Comment: Add some jsfiddle link to get to actual problem.

Comment: Do you want the `commentsValue` in `starLeft` your function on clicking it?

Comment: Use **ng-model=commentsValue** not in quoted strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$scope.starLeft = function(event,commentsValue, name){
    if(commentsValue =='' || commentsValue === undefined){
        alert('please enter comments');
        return;
    }
  alert(name)
}
```

```html
<td>{{x.name}}</td>
<td>
    <div ng-click="starHovered($event)" class='pointer fg-blue'>{{x.star}} </div>
    <div title='Click to add star' class='displayNone'><input type="text-box" placeholder="Enter comments" class='commentsValue' ng-model=commentsValue/><img  ng-click="starLeft($event,commentsValue, x.name)" class='pointer' src='images/add.png' height='30px'/></div>
</td>
```

Comment: I want the value of name, i.e value in parent td, which is equivalent to $(this).parent().parent().children().eq(0).text()..

Comment: You want **x.name** value?

Comment: yes, that to on clicking the image. generally i want first td value when i click second td

Comment: If you look at ng-click on img tag already there is parameter added for **x.name** which you can later access in your function as a third parameter.

Comment: good suggestion and it works, thanks but assume that someone needs to take value from any particular container in dom then how will they.